# Web scraping coinmarketcap - not getting all data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to collect data from coinmarketcap.com, but when I scrape the webpage for the prices, I can only retrieve the first 11 prices. I managed to get the 100 coin names on the first page (of course with some help from someone on stackoverflow), but for prices i get only 11. I "inspect" the source, and right click-> copy xpath. I see that the price contains /currencies/name of the coin/markets, so i use "contains". But for I am missing something.

```
coin_name = [name.text for name in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[3]/a[@class="cmc-link" and starts-with(@href, "/currencies/")]')]
print(coin_name)
print(len(coin_name))
price = [p.text for p in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[4]/div/a[@class = "cmc-link" and contains(@href, "/markets/")]')]
print(price)
print(len(price))
```

Output for print(len(coin_name)) is 100, and print(len(price)) is 11

Comment: I don't know the site, but a WAG would be that they are loading the data using any one of a dozen different AJAX mechanisms. Try going to the page in either Chrome or Firefox and pressing F12. You'll get a a full debugging console + lots of tools. If it *is* an AJAX load, then life is going to be more difficult for you.

Comment: You have a space after `cmc-link` maybe this will solve the problem

Comment: The space was the problem, but now I can only retrieve the first 11. It seems to cut-off after the 11th coin, which is strange because the xpath is the same I can see.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you comment @arundeepchohan

Comment: Nevermind just switch to //a[@class = "cmc-link" and contains(@href, "/markets/")] and got all 200.

Comment: Nice tip, but I get 22, and it does not give prices.